# How to hook up an alternative destination for Debug.Writeline() and Debug.Write()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am relatively new to .net world, I have a solution where there are hundreds of Debug.Writeline and Debug.Write.
 I need to send the message to a text file and a database instead of traditional output.

replacing all Debug.XXX line and sending those particular messages to my destinations is tedious and not recommended task.

so how should I hook up an alternative destination ?

One way is to override  Debug.Write() functionality, which is not working.

kindly help me and thanks in advance

Comment: Be aware that all calls to `Debug.WriteLine` and its siblings are **removed** in a RELEASE-build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inherit your own [`TraceListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracelistener):

```
public class MyTraceListener : TraceListener
{
    // called (in debug-mode) when Debug.Write() is called
    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        // handle/output "message" properly
    }
    // called (in debug-mode) when Debug.WriteLine() is called
    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        // handle/output "message" properly
    }
}
```

You then need to register an instance of this class (using `Trace.Listeners.Add()`:

```
var myListener = new MyTraceListener();
Trace.Listeners.Add(myListener);
```

---

Now all calls to `Debug.Write()` and `Debug.WriteLine()` are forwarded to the respective methods of your instance of `MyTraceListener`. **Note** however that this only happens in DEBUG builds. In RELEASE builds, calls to `Debug.Write()` and `Debug.WriteLine()` don't do anything.

Comment: thanks really helpful  I need in Debug builds only, but I have a doubt because of my short experience ,  creating only one instance  of tracer will resolve the issue in entire solution which contains 10+ projects ? if so what could be the best place to create instance. sorry if told something out of way

Comment: @ManojKalluri yes, one listener per **process** is enough (no matter how many assemblies the process loads). _Where_ to put the code depends on your solution architecture, I can't tell you that.